# Python Stacked Bar colored by Category

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a csv dataset that looks like:

```
Account     Months_since_Open      Gender      Age_Group
XXXXX              12               Male       Millennial
YYYYY              24               Female        71+
ZZZZZ              20               Female        55-70
```

The dataset continues for millions of rows. basically i want a bar chart that has Months_Since_Open on the x-axis and Number of accounts(Frequency) on the Y-axis. Furthermore, i want the bars to be colored by age group.

So far this is what i have:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import statsmodels.api as sm 
import pylab as pl 
from scipy import stats 
from sklearn.externals.six import StringIO 
from sklearn import preprocessing 
from sklearn import cluster, tree, decomposition 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import pydot 
import os
import seaborn as sns

df1 = pd.read_csv("LiveSeg.csv")


sexgroup = df.groupby('Gender')
Female = df[(df['Gender'] == 'FEMALE')]
plt.hist(Female.AcctAge_Months.dropna(),bins =50)
```

This gives me the following output:
[image]

How can i have these bars colored by the % of clients in the age group? I am using python 3.4.4 Thanks

Comment: So, basically you want each bar to be of a different colour?

Comment: No, I want each bar to be colored according to thier age_group. Basically, if Millennials opened 50% of the accounts in one of those bars then i want that bar to be colored 50% yellow, the next 25% were from age group 71+ then the bar should be 50% yellow, 25% Red and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to return and save the histogram from matplotlib to be able to color each bar differently.

First of all, your code

```
sexgroup = df.groupby('Gender')
female = df[(df['Gender'] == 'FEMALE')]
```

does not make sense to me, either just use

```
female = df[(df['Gender'] == 'FEMALE')]
```

or use a more readable pandas way

```
female = df.groupby('Gender').get_group('FEMALE')
```

When plotting, just save the return of your histgram call:

```
counts, edges, patches = plt.hist(Female.AcctAge_Months.dropna(), bins = 50)
```

The return of `plt.hist` is a tuple containing counts, histogram edges and a list of the matplotlib `patch` objects that are displayed. Now to color each bar individually, just call:

```
patches[0].set_color('r')
```

I assume you want a specific color in percentage of red, yellow, green, depending on some percentage. So instead of the `'r'` parameter passed to `set_color`, pass a tuple with RGB values in it like so:

```
color = (0.5,0.25,0.25)
patches[0].set_color(color)
```

From your question, it is not clear how you calculate the '% of clients in the age group', as it is unclear, what the DataFrame column `AcctAge_Months` is. I assume you'll just devide the count of each DataFrame group by it's size, e.g. from `df.groupby('Gender').count()`.

Basically, just loop over each patch of the histogram and set the color in RGB, while the percentage of each color component has to be calculated from your '% of clients in the age group'.